# HTML Purifier Config File

Tags: config, json

I noticed the following new feature in Craft CMS [2.6.2973](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-6-2973): *Added the “HTML Purifier Config” setting to Rich Text fields*.

I can't see any mention or any example of config files in the Craft CMS [docs for Rich Text fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/rich-text-fields) though, and the only thing I can see in the Rich Text Field settings in the control panel is this:

> You can save custom HTML Purifier configs as .json files in craft/config/htmlpurifier/. [View available settings](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html)

Can someone help me with a custom HTML Purifier config .json file that I can use with Craft that would allow me to start using YouTube video embed code like this in Rich Text fields?

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HdYfAmrzVlc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

At the moment, the above code will disappear when saving an entry unless I disable the *Purify HTML?* option in the Rich Text field settings. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this in a `.json` file should work:

```
{
  "HTML.SafeIframe": true,
  "URI.SafeIframeRegexp": "%^(https?:)?//(www\\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\\.com/embed/)%",
  "Attr.AllowedFrameTargets": ["_blank"],
  "HTML.AllowedComments": ["pagebreak"]
}
```

Note that the first two lines were adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784081/684 and the last two are the default options that Craft uses if no custom config is set.

Probably also worth giving this a read: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-youtube.html

Comment: Just note that the HtmlPurifier link is pretty out of date since it talks about YouTube videos as being a Flash embed. I think they've been using iframes for a few years now which have a better security model.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying Brad! Just a quick comment to say that this did the trick for me, thanks.

Comment: What should the json file be named though? Cant find any info on that

Comment: Any filename will do, then you can choose your config in the "Advanced" tab in your Craft field settings under "HTML Purifier Config".

Answer (score 3):

Following from Brad's answer (I'm not able to comment) I had to escape the backslashes to avoid JSON decode error.

Version for Youtube and Vimeo

```
{
    "HTML.SafeIframe": true,
    "URI.SafeIframeRegexp": "%^(https?:)?//(www\\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\\.com/embed/|player\\.vimeo\\.com/video/)%",
    "Attr.AllowedFrameTargets": ["_blank"],
    "HTML.AllowedComments": ["pagebreak"]
}
```

Or just YouTube

```
{
    "HTML.SafeIframe": true,
    "URI.SafeIframeRegexp": "%^(https?:)?//(www\\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\\.com/embed/)%",
    "Attr.AllowedFrameTargets": ["_blank"],
    "HTML.AllowedComments": ["pagebreak"]
}
```

Comment: What should be the name of the config file? No one ever mentions that, are all files in config/htmlpurifier/*.json loaded automatically? I've tried adding one named the same as my redactor config file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any filename will do, then you can choose your config in the "Advanced" tab in your Craft field settings under "HTML Purifier Config".